# Conditional Probability with complements

Tags: probability

Events A and B are such that P(A)=0.7, P(B)=0.2, and P(A∩B)=0.2. Find P(A|B').

I found out that P(A u B) = 0.7, but I'm not sure how to work out the conditional probability - I've tried using the formula and I got P(A|B') = (0.7*0.8)/0.8, but that seems wrong.

Comment: Do you know the definition of conditional probability? Do you know $P(B')$?

Comment: P(B') = 1 - P(B) = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8

Comment: Good. You'll need the definition of conditional probability: $$P(A \mid B') = \frac{P(A \cap B')}{P(B')}$$ and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm not seeing your tex code as proper symbols. Is there a plugin/program I should be installing?

Comment: Is P(A∩B′) = P(A) * P(B') ?

Comment: Not in general. Only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. Seems like you need to review your textbook or course notes.

Comment: So would P(A u B') = 1 - P(B) - P(A n B) (from drawing the venn diagram)? Not sure to include the intersection of A and B or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$P(A\mid B')=\frac{P(A\cap B')}{P(B')}=\frac{P(A)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$P(A) = P(A\cap \Omega) = P(A\cap (B\cup B')) = P((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B')) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B')$$

$\Omega$ here represents the probability space.

We know that $P(A)=0.7$ and we know that $P(A\cap B)=0.2$ so...

Comment: I'm not sure why this received a downvote.  It seemed to me that the only piece of information the OP was missing to finish solving was how to find $P(A\cap B')$, which the above work shows that $P(A\cap B')=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$, just as the other answer said without proof.